# Javascript: how to draw a chart from this JSON dataset?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a webpage where I pull stock prices from Yahoo Finance and to display the data in a chart. This is a project I am working on, as part of a course I am taking.

I managed to retrieve the data. I can also make a basic chart, using Dygraphs. However, I do not know how to combine the two, i.e. how to draw a chart on the data I got from Yahoo Finance.

The problem is that the data I retrieve from Yahoo Finance is under JSON format, while Dygraphs accepts data formatted as csv.

I am trying to parse the JSON dataset and create a string formatted as csv, so as to feed it to Dygraphs, but I have not yet been successful.

I am new to HTML/CSS/Javascript and I am struggling. Could anyone suggest a direction?
- Which functions can I use to parse the data in a format that Dygraphs can use?
- Or should I try to get the data under a different format (this is what I have been trying at first, but I did not succeed)?
- Or should I switch to another charting library that works with JSON?

Here is the code I have to retrieve the data from Yahoo Finance (it is mostly taken from www.fincluster.com):
http://jsfiddle.net/lcazarre/Eajt6/

Javascript:

```
(function($) {
    function getStock(type, complete) {
        var defs = {
            desc: false,
            baseURL: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=',
            query: {
                quotes: 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = "{stock}" | sort(field="{sortBy}", descending="{desc}")',
                historicaldata: 'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "{stock}" and startDate = "{startDate}" and endDate = "{endDate}"'
            },
            suffixURL: {
                quotes: '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json&callback=?',
                historicaldata: '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json&callback=?'
            }
        };

        var query = defs.query[type]
        .replace('{stock}', $("#inputSymbol").val())
        .replace('{sortBy}', defs.sortBy)
        .replace('{desc}', defs.desc)
        .replace('{startDate}', $("#startDate").val())
        .replace('{endDate}', $("#endDate").val())

        var url = defs.baseURL + query + (defs.suffixURL[type] || '');
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            var err = null;
            if (!data || !data.query) {
                err = true;
            }
            complete(err, !err && data.query.results);
            alert(data.query.results);
        });
    }
    window.getStock = getStock;
})(jQuery);
```

HTML:

```
<body>
<div id="maindiv">

    <header>
        <hgroup>
            <h1> Retrieve stock information </h1>
            <h6> (Data provided by Yahoo! Finance) </h6> 
        </hgroup>
    </header>

    <div>
        <p>Input a list of tickers (e.g. "AAPL" for Apple Inc), separated by commas</p>
        <input type="text" id="inputSymbol" />

        <p>Input the start date, formatted as 'YYYY-DD-MM'</p>
        <input type="text" id="startDate" />

        <p>Input the end date, formatted as 'YYYY-DD-MM'</p>
        <input type="text" id="endDate" />

        <p>Click on the button to launch the query</p>
        <button type="submit" onclick="getStock('historicaldata', function(err, data) {
            console.log(data);
        });">Add the tickers to the table</button>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you can pass a function that returns the data:

> {String | Function} **file**
>   A file containing CSV data or **a function that returns this data**. The most basic expected format for each line is "YYYY/MM/DD,val1,val2,...". For more information, see http://dygraphs.com/data.html.

Following the link and looking for the "function" they speak of:
http://dygraphs.com/data.html#function
The only note they left was:

> Functions can return strings, arrays, data tables, URLs, or any other data type.

I would suggest trying to pass in various types of data similar to the csv file to see how the chart works.

Comment: Thanks. I finally managed to feed digraphs with data under csv format. It was actually not too hard, but I am very new to Javascript and I have everything to learn. See my answer below for details.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to format the data for Dygraphs:

```
(function($) {
    function getStock(type, complete) {
        var defs = {
            desc: false,
            baseURL: 'http://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=',
            query: {
                quotes: 'select * from yahoo.finance.quotes where symbol = "{stock}" | sort(field="{sortBy}", descending="{desc}")',
                historicaldata: 'select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "{stock}" and startDate = "{startDate}" and endDate = "{endDate}"'
            },
            suffixURL: {
                quotes: '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json&callback=?',
                historicaldata: '&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys&format=json&callback=?'
            }
        };

        var query = defs.query[type]
        .replace('{stock}', $("#inputSymbol").val())
        .replace('{sortBy}', defs.sortBy)
        .replace('{desc}', defs.desc)
        .replace('{startDate}', $("#startDate").val())
        .replace('{endDate}', $("#endDate").val())

        var url = defs.baseURL + query + (defs.suffixURL[type] || '');
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            var err = null;
            if (!data || !data.query) {
                err = true;
            }
            complete(err, !err && data.query.results);
            //alert(data.query.results);

            //loop object by keys
            var textCsv = "";
            var tempData = data.query.results.quote;
            var dataCsv = "Date,Close\n"
            for (var key in tempData) {
                dataCsv += tempData[key].Date;
                dataCsv += ",";
                dataCsv += tempData[key].Close;
                dataCsv += "\n";
            }
            g = new Dygraph(document.getElementById("graphdiv"), dataCsv);

        });
    }

    window.getStock = getStock;
})(jQuery);
```